# XSLT dont add XMLNS to elements

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a simple HTML fragment similar to this:

```
<a href="123">link</a>
```

I need to transform it to

```
<abc:href var="123">link</abc:href>
```

I do it with XSLT, so I had to add the namespace in `xsl:stylesheet`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:abc="http://abc.ru">
```

It works almost fine, unfortunately the XSLT transform keeps on adding a XMLNS to the output, like here:

```
<abc:href var="123" xmlns:abc="http://abc.ru">link</abc:href>
```

I don't need the xmlns definition, can I remove it?

Comment: So in your output document, where should the namespace node for abc go? At the root level? It cannot be without because then it would be a malformed document.

Comment: You should not be trying to produce invalid XML with XSLT. If you use a namespace prefix, it must be defined some where in your document, or  your document becomes malformed.

Comment: the `xmlns` is already defined in an external document..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it really goes against the grain, and I advise strongly against it, if you need to produce this malformed XML, then you can use an instruction like...

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="
  concat('&lt;abc:href var="',$href,'"&gt;',$link,'&lt;/abc:href&gt;')
 "/>
```

... where $href and $link are place-markers for the appropriate expression.

---

### Update

In response to the OP's comment, one could use a template like this...

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="
    concat('&lt;abc:href var="',@href,'"&gt;',.,'&lt;/abc:href&gt;')
   "/>
</xsl:template>
```

This ugly solution should be used only as a last resort. A much better solution would be to use XSLT to produce your WHOLE document, not just an invalid fragment of it. This way you document would be well formed and you could bring to bear the full power and simplicity of XSLT.

Comment: how would I fill the placeholders?

Comment: This is the closest to what I'd expect, thank you. Im not sure if I'll stick keep XSLT at all, though..

Answer (score 1):

> It works almost fine, unfortunately the XSLT transform keeps on adding
>   a XMLNS to the output, like here:
>
> ```
> <abc:href var="123" xmlns:abc="http://abc.ru">link</abc:href>
> ```
>
> I don't need the xmlns definition, can I remove it?

**The wanted removal of the namespace declaration would produce a (namespace-)non-well-formed XML document** and for this reason the XSLT processor adds the namespace declaration -- as required by the W3C XSLT specifications.

**You can cause these namespace declarations to "disappear"** by placing the namespace declaration on a common ancestor (such as the top element of the generated XML document).

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <top xmlns:abc="http://abc.ru">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </top>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a[@href]">
   <xsl:element name="abc:href" namespace="http://abc.ru">
     <xsl:attribute name="var">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following document**:

```
<html>
  <a href="123">link1</a>
  <a href="xxx">link2</a>
  <a href="yyy">link3</a>
  <a href="zzz">link4</a>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<top xmlns:abc="http://abc.ru">
   <abc:href var="link1"/>
   <abc:href var="link2"/>
   <abc:href var="link3"/>
   <abc:href var="link4"/>
</top>
```

Comment: not bad, but still not what I need. This is sad, but I really need an invalid xml .. ;-)

Comment: @Queequeg, You need to realize the consequences of producing non-well-formed XML -- for example, you will not be able to further evaluate XPath expressions on this result or to further process it as XML document with XSLT (or with any processor that expects well-formed XML document as its input).

Comment: I understand. If the "guidelines" are the only problem here, then don't worry. If it's technology  - then , well.. I'll try to move to regexes..

Comment: @Queequeg, You *can* produce malformed output with XSLT -- either use DOE (as per Sean's answer) or `<xsl:output method="text"/>`. As for processing the result further with RegEx, while this surely can be done, it is similar to intentionally breaking down all your computers and then counting with your fingers.

Comment: If I use method text then I have to manually write all the xml tags, don't I? A quick test shows that only elements' inner text gets printed, in my case the output would be just `link`

Comment: @Queequeg, Correct. DOE would be more "convenient". Do note, however, that DOE isn't a mandatory feature of XSLT and not all XSLT processors implement it. So, you need to verify that your XSLT processor supports DOE. And, of course, using DOE means that your transformation loses portability and it won't be possible to run it with every XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1):

> This is sad, but I really need an invalid xml

XSLT is designed to prevent you producing bad XML. If you want to produce bad XML, don't use XSLT.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with `exclude-result-prefixes`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:abc="http://abc.ru"
                exclude-result-prefixes="abc">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
     <href var="{@href}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></href>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is wrong as well, as it won't produce the required outcome.

Comment: the output would be `<href var="123">link</a>", not `<abc:href>` I want to remove the `xmlns` attribute, not the namespace prefix in element-name

Comment: Okay, so you want to have the namespace prefix in place but you do not want to define it (neither in root nor in the element itself). Since your requirement is an invalid XML, XSLT seems to be a bad solution for this.